# Image size reduces while it send through "ShareMediaTask" in windows phone 8

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, gmail, hotmail

In my image editing application i am providing two option to the user, 1) save image to Media library and another share it through ShareMediaTask. The issue i am facing is while saving the image to library the size of the image is 1.5 mb. If i share the same image through ShareMediaTask(Gmail / Hotmail etc) The size of the image reduces to 330 Kb. Hence it affects the quality of the image. How i can share the same image in Media library without losing the size and quality in windows phone 8.

I also tried the same share through library (ie without using my application). Still the result is same.

If anyone had a solution to this issue please update your suggestions.

Thanks,

Stez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email application automatically downscales images, there is no way to control this. An alternative solution would be to, eg, upload the image to Skydrive and email the link.